# FFmpeg codec internal error with my decoder

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, openmax

`Hey, I write a ffmpeg codec based on openmax. It can run success with my test code or ffmpeg test. However it run with error when I use it in chrome.
The error is
[3845:3880:0710/110530.508867:ERROR:ffmpeg_video_decoder.cc(487)] avcodec_open2 failed.-558323010
[3845:3880:0710/110530.509921:ERROR:ffmpeg_video_decoder.cc(491)] avcodec_open2 error: Internal bug, should not have happened

now I am confused with open the ffmpeg logging in chrome , so I can't resolve this problem.

The following is my codec settings:

```
#define OFFSET(x) offsetof(OMXCodecDecoderContext, x)
#define VDE AV_OPT_FLAG_VIDEO_PARAM | AV_OPT_FLAG_DECODING_PARAM | AV_OPT_FLAG_ENCODING_PARAM
#define VE  AV_OPT_FLAG_VIDEO_PARAM | AV_OPT_FLAG_ENCODING_PARAM
#define VD  AV_OPT_FLAG_VIDEO_PARAM | AV_OPT_FLAG_DECODING_PARAM

static const AVOption options[] = {
    { "omx_libname", "OpenMAX library name", OFFSET(libname), AV_OPT_TYPE_STRING, { 0 }, 0, 0, VDE },
    { "omx_libprefix", "OpenMAX library prefix", OFFSET(libprefix), AV_OPT_TYPE_STRING, { 0 }, 0, 0, VDE },   
    { "profile",  "Set the Decoding profile", OFFSET(profile), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT,   { .i64 = FF_PROFILE_UNKNOWN },       FF_PROFILE_UNKNOWN, FF_PROFILE_H264_HIGH, VE, "profile" },
    { "baseline", "",                         0,               AV_OPT_TYPE_CONST, { .i64 = FF_PROFILE_H264_BASELINE }, 0, 0, VE, "profile" },
    { "main",     "",                         0,               AV_OPT_TYPE_CONST, { .i64 = FF_PROFILE_H264_MAIN },     0, 0, VE, "profile" },
    { "high",     "",                         0,               AV_OPT_TYPE_CONST, { .i64 = FF_PROFILE_H264_HIGH },     0, 0, VE, "profile" },
    { NULL }
};


static const AVCodecHWConfigInternal *const omx_hw_configs[] = {
    &(const AVCodecHWConfigInternal) {
        .public          = {
            .pix_fmt     = AV_PIX_FMT_NV12,
            .methods     = AV_CODEC_HW_CONFIG_METHOD_AD_HOC |
                           AV_CODEC_HW_CONFIG_METHOD_HW_DEVICE_CTX,
            .device_type = AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_MEDIACODEC,
        },
        .hwaccel         = NULL,
    },
    NULL
};


static const AVOption ff_omxcodec_vdec_options[] = {
    { "delay_flush", "Delay flush until hw output buffers are returned to the decoder",
                     OFFSET(delay_flush), AV_OPT_TYPE_BOOL, {.i64 = 0}, 0, 1, VD },
    { NULL }
};

#define DECLARE_OMX_VCLASS(short_name)                          \
static const AVClass ff_##short_name##_omxcodec_dec_class = {   \
    .class_name = #short_name "_libomxh264",                    \
    .item_name  = av_default_item_name,                         \
    .option     = ff_omxcodec_vdec_options,                     \
    .version    = LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_INT,                        \
};

#define DECLARE_OMX_VDEC(short_name, full_name, codec_id, bsf)                          \
DECLARE_OMX_VCLASS(short_name)                                                          \
const FFCodec ff_ ## short_name ## _omx_decoder = {                                     \
    .p.name         = #short_name "_omxcodec",                             \
    CODEC_LONG_NAME(full_name " OpenMAX IL decoder"),                      \
    .p.type         = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,                                  \
    .p.id           = codec_id,                                            \
    .p.priv_class   = &ff_##short_name##_omxcodec_dec_class,               \
    .priv_data_size = sizeof(OMXCodecDecoderContext),                      \
    .init           = omx_decode_init,                                     \
    FF_CODEC_DECODE_CB(omx_decode_frame),                                  \
    .close          = omx_decode_end,                                      \
    .flush          = omx_decode_flush,                                    \
    .p.capabilities = AV_CODEC_CAP_DELAY | AV_CODEC_CAP_AVOID_PROBING | AV_CODEC_CAP_HARDWARE, \
    .caps_internal  = FF_CODEC_CAP_NOT_INIT_THREADSAFE |                                       \
                      FF_CODEC_CAP_SETS_PKT_DTS,                                               \
    .bsfs           = bsf,                                                                     \
    .hw_configs     = omx_hw_configs,                                                          \
    .p.wrapper_name = "omxcodec",                                                              \
}; 

DECLARE_OMX_VDEC(h264,  "H.264", AV_CODEC_ID_H264, "h264_mp4toannexb")
DECLARE_OMX_VDEC(hevc,  "H.265", AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC, "hevc_mp4toannexb")
DECLARE_OMX_VDEC(mpeg4, "MPEG-4", AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4, NULL)
```

can someone give me a advice to resolve this problem?

Comment: I found how to enable ffmpeg logging on Chrome source code, it haven't enable h264_mp4toannexb yet, so ... ,Thx.